# sourcing a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Recently, I came across the Linux command `source` and then found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) on what it does.

My understanding was that `source` executes the file that is passed to it, and it did work for a simple shell script.  Then I tried using `source` on a Python script–but it did not work.

The Python script has a shebang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`) and I am able to do a `./python.py`, as the script has executable permission.  If that is possible, `source python.py` should also be possible, right?  The only difference is `./` executes in a new shell and `source` executes in the current shell.  Why is it not working on a `.py` script?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Source doesn't execute the file, it executes the commands from the file as if you just typed them in the current shell.

Comment: [`./python.py` is not equivalent to `source python.py`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182012/is-there-a-difference-between-and-source-in-bash-after-all)

Comment: The most common use case for running a script in the current shell instead of in a subshell is when you want to set environment variables or other tasks belonging to a `.profile` or `.bashrc`. There is little use for `source` besides that.

Comment: @PauloScardine `alias` is a big one, actually.  But yes, the most common things are those you'd otherwise find in a `.profile` or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're still not quite on-target understanding what `source` does.

`source` does indeed execute commands from a file in the current shell process.  It does this effectively as if you had typed them directly into your current shell.

The reason this is necessary is because when you run a shell script without sourcing it, it will spawn a subshell—a new process.  When this process exits, any changes made within that script are lost as you return to the shell from which it spawned.

It follows, then, that you cannot source Python into a shell, because the Python interpreter is always a different process from your shell.  Running a Python script spawns a brand-new process, and when that process exits, its state is lost.

Of course, if your shell *is* actually Python (which I would not recommend!), you can still "source" into it—by using `import`.

Comment: Unless you change your login shell to `/usr/bin/python` that is =p

Comment: @D.Shawley Heh.  Actually, though, there's actually a great parallel there, between `source` and `import`.

Comment: Actually a normal import wouldn't really emulate the semantics of the shell "source" command.  "from ... import *" would be closer ... modifying your Python sessions state and globals namespace more similarly.

Answer (score 3):

`source` executes the files and places whatever functions/aliases/environment variables created in that script within the shell that called it.  It does this by not spawning a new process, but instead executing the script in the current process.

The shabang is used by the shell to indicate what to use to spawn the new process, so for `source` it is ignored, and the file is interpreted as the language of the current process (`bash` in this case).  This is why using `source` on a python file failed for you.