# Applying source on Python script to export environment variables?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

**Context:**

I'm working with a few developers, some on OSX and some on Linux. We use a collection of bash scripts to load environment variables, build docker images etc. The OSX users are using zsh instead of bash, so some tricks (specifically how we're getting the running script's directory) aren't compatible. What works on Linux (but not OSX) is:

```sh
$ cat ./scripts/env_script.sh
THIS_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
# ... more variables ...
$ source ./scripts/env_script.sh
$ echo $THIS_DIR
# the absolute path to the scripts directory
```

Some cursory testing shows this doesn't work on OSX, presumably because `BASH_SOURCE` doesn't work the same with zsh. Fine.

**Goal:**

We're all working with a Python, we would like to replace our bash scripts with Python.
The same pattern is very easy in Python.

```py
from pathlib import Path
THIS_DIR = str(Path(__file__).parent)
```

Not the cleanest, but it works anywhere. Ideally we could run this and share `THIS_DIR` with the shell that called the script. Something like

```sh
$ <answer to my question> ./scripts/env_script.py
$ echo $THIS_DIR
# absolute path to the scripts directory
```

**Question:**

Suppose we rewrote our `./scripts/env_script.sh` into `./scripts/env_script.py` and collected a list of variables we would like to share with the calling environment.
That is, we wrote the Python script above.

Is it possible to do something akin to `source ./scripts/env_script.py` so that we can export the variables from the Python script into the calling shell?

**What I've tried:**

- I found a potential duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577555/sourcing-a-python-script) though the answer is basically 'Python runs in a sub-process, source would only work if your shell *is* Python` which makes sense but doesn't answer the question.
- If there isn't a nice way to exchange these variables, then another option would basically be to have the Python script spit the variables to stdout and then eval them within my shell. I.e. `eval $(./script/env_script.py)`. I guess this could work, but it feels wrong at least because I was always taught `eval` is evil.

Comment: `BASH_SOURCE` is built into bash, and should work in every bash. Of course it would not work in zsh, but I don't understand why you mention zsh, because it is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @user1934428 I mention zsh because my colleagues are all using zsh on OSX. I just assumed that was the default, but the underlying problem is we want to have environment-agnostic variables.

Comment: Every user decides for himself, what shell to use. Some might even use tcsh (we never know). However, you just want to load common settings in Python applications. This is not related to the shell being used to run your Python program. IMO, this is a pure Python problem.

Comment: I'm also interested in this kind of solution. But I guess, the best way would be to create a POSIX script to work with both Linux and MacOS. I always test my scripts on FreeBSD so that they work on most POSIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a little more time on the second solution since I could imagine it working (although I'm not happy with it). Basically, I rewrite `./scripts/env_script.py` to be

```py
FOO='whatever'
THIS_DIR=str(Path(__file__).parent)
# and so on...

# prints all "normal" variables to stdout
def_vars = list(locals().items())
for name, val in def_vars:
    if name.startswith("_"):
        continue
    print(f'{name}="{val}"')
```

So running it normally would output

```sh
$ ./scripts/env_script.py
FOO="whatever"
THIS_DIR="..."
...
$ echo $FOO
# nothing
```

Then, to jam those variables into the calling shell, we wrap that with [eval](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) and it does the job

```sh
$ eval $(./scripts/env_script.py)
$ echo $FOO
whatever
```

I guess with some further tweaking, the footer at the end of `env_script.py` could be made a little more robust, and then moved outside of the script. Some sort of alias could be defined to make it syntactically nicer, so then calling it could like `pysource ./scripts/env_script.py`. Still, I'm not satisfied with this answer.

Edit: I did the tweaking and wrote a downloadable script [here](https://gitlab.com/afiorillo/pysource).